# I have error with kick command "TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Here is my error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function
```

I don't know what the error is at line 5, I hope to find a solution thanks to you if you help me!

And here is my code:

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js");
 
module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
 
    let kUser = message.guild.member (message.mentions.users.first () || message.guild.members.get (args [0]));
    if (! kickUser) return message.channel.send ("I can't find this user");
    let KickReason = args.join ("") .slice (22);
    if (! message.member.hasPermission ("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send ("You don't have permissions");
    if (kickUser.hasPermission ("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send ("This user cannot be kicked or banned");
 
    let KickEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed ()
    .setTitle ("__ ** KICK ** __")
        .setColor ("# bc0000")
        .setDescription (`$ {kickUser} has been kicked by <@ $ {message.author.id}> in the channel: $ {message.channel}. Reason for the kick: $ {KickReason}`);
 
        let KickChannel = message.guild.channels.find (`name`," incidents ")
    if (! KickChannel) return message.channel.send ("I can't find the` incidents` channel if it doesn't exist, please create it. ")
 
    message.guild.member (kickUser) .kick (KickReason)
    KickChannel.send (KickEmbed);
 
    return;
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "kick"
}
```

Comment: What is the output? How to do you know the error is in "line 5"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't put all the error, and don't worry I'm not so stupid as to say a line in my head :')

Comment: I didn't imply you were stupid, and saying that to someone who is trying to help you could be considered inappropriate by some. The message `TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function` is actually helpful.

Comment: What is the output if you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(message))` as the first line of your function?